# Attaching a tag

Tags: tags, tagging, tag-cloud

What is the actual procedure for attaching multiple tags to a particular content in a project development. What is this tagging all about???

I need to create a tag cloud for my project in .NET using c#. Help me out as a beginner for basic tagging concept.

Comment: This question is a bit vague as to what domain of project development you are referring to. Do elaborate.

Comment: Are you talking about setting up Tags in SVN for your projects?

Answer (score 1):

Tags are key words add information about the item being tagged. Tags add semantic information about something in an effort to further it.

For instance, A picture of your father on his birthday could be tagged 'dad','family','event','birthday' etc...

By adding tags to the picture you add context and make the image more easily indexable, sortable and searchable.

Tags are purposely generic and flexible because different people can place different personal meaning to the same artifact, or the same person may apply different meaning in different contexts - like adding the same picture to a stock photography web site or checking it into a source code repository as part of a project.

Generally the procedure is to ask the owner of the item to add a list of tags in a text field. Some sites like stackoverflow constrain (most) users to use existing tags, others like delicious make the tags up to the user.

Answer (score 0):

A tag in the software context typically means a meaningful name or attribute being assigned to that software.  In version control scenarios a tag is a meaningful name given to a particular state of the files represented by that name.  For example the tag 20090401 might be assigned to the source code as it looked on April 1, 2009.  Tagging something can also mean describing it or categorizing it.  For example software such as IE8, Chrome, or Firefox might all be tagged "Browsers" to categorize them on a download page.  Allowing users to create tags and use existing tags is a powerful method to categorize content and help people zero in on items of interest.  A tag is simply an extra tidbit of information a person can gain insight into data with.

Multiple tagging is useful for many reasons in software development.  For example in my git repository I have a habit of creating tags based on date which can easily be ordered and parsed by a computer.  I can also give changes a more human consumable name such as the tag "Deleted_Duplicates", or "RC1", or "V1_Delievered_To_Michigan".  This allows for an understanding while also allowing for machine processing.